# У SVG скошенная линия

Tags: html, css, svg

```css
svg {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     width="350px"  
     height="70px"
     preserveAspectRatio="none"
     transform="scale(1,-1)">
  <path d="M 0,0
           L 20,90
           L 40 10
           L 70 10" 
        fill="none" 
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke="#886ce6"
        stroke-width="5px"/>

</svg>
```

как мне сделать край линии прямоугольным? Так же линии имеют разную ширину. Может это и очевидно, но как этого избежать? svg для меня пока еще слабо знаком просто

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотри, у тебя вьюбокс базовый - 100 на 100 пикселей, а ты его растянул 350 на 70, поэтому и линии могут быть разные.

Кроме того странное transform="scale(1,-1) - это для чего?

stroke-linecap - отвечает за углы, возможные значения: butt, round, square.
у тебя - round, это их и круглит. Или удалить или поменять на square например.

Comment: углы становятся острыми.. Изменил `viewBox="0 0 100 100"` на `viewBox="0 0 350 70"` и это помогло!) спасибо. Я просто хотел с удобством использовать проценты. ` transform="scale(1,-1)` для того, чтобы перевернуть svg в привычную систему координат

Comment: По трансформ - понял идею))

Comment: там чтобы норм работало надо прописать `transform: scale(1,-1); transform-origin: 50%;`. Вдруг пригодится кому